# конвертирование цветов формата RGB в XYZ

Tags: python, python-3.x, color, rgb

Имеется задача конвертирования цветов. Мне необходимо добиться того результата, что выдает сайт:

https://colorscheme.ru/color-converter.html

Предположим, что есть цвет формата

`RGB = [0, 2, 100]`,

необходимо перевести его в

```
XYZ = [2, 1, 12]
```

> Цветовая модель XYZ (CIE 1931 XYZ) является чисто математическим пространством. В отличие от RGB, CMYK, и других моделей, в XYZ основные компоненты являются «мнимыми», то есть вы не можете соотнести X, Y, и Z с каким-либо набором цветов для смешивания. XYZ является мастер-моделью практически всех остальных цветовых моделей, используемых в технических областях.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Там достаточно замороченная формула перевода: https://traditio.wiki/XYZ_(%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)

Comment: [sRGB The reverse transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#The_reverse_transformation)

Comment: Библиотека https://python-colormath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conversions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот мое решение:

```
def funXYZ(RGB):
    var_R = (RGB[0] / 255)
    var_G = (RGB[1] / 255)
    var_B = (RGB[2] / 255)

    if var_R > 0.04045:
        var_R = ((var_R + 0.055) / 1.055) ** 2.4
    else:
        var_R = var_R / 12.92
    if var_G > 0.04045:
        var_G = ((var_G + 0.055) / 1.055) ** 2.4
    else:
        var_G = var_G / 12.92
    if var_B > 0.04045:
        var_B = ((var_B + 0.055) / 1.055) ** 2.4
    else:
        var_B = var_B / 12.92

    X = (var_R * 0.4124 + var_G * 0.3576 + var_B * 0.1805) * 100
    Y = (var_R * 0.2126 + var_G * 0.7152 + var_B * 0.0722) * 100
    Z = (var_R * 0.0193 + var_G * 0.1192 + var_B * 0.9505) * 100
    return X, Y, Z
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
import numpy as np
import colour                                  #   pip install colour-science

RGB = np.array([0, 2, 100])
XYZ = colour.sRGB_to_XYZ(RGB / 255)

print(XYZ)
print([ round(i*100) for i in XYZ.tolist()])
```